# Changing airline in Sydney. Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, australia, filipino-citizens

We are Filipino citizens flying from Manila to Auckland, New Zealand using two different airlines. There’s a 9-hour wait after we arrive in Sydney, then we fly from Sydney to NZ is a different airline.

Do we need to apply for a transit visa? If so, can we also leave the airport and do some sightseeing for a few hours?

Comment: what citizenship do you have and how long is the transit?

Comment: Hi! Philippines and  layover is 9 hours

Answer (score 1):

You will need a transit visa and to re-check your luggage as your stay exceeds 8 hours:

> Transit visa. This visa lets people be in Australia for up to 72 hours before they must leave Australia.

([Source](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771))

You can leave the airport:

> Any citizens who need to leave the airport transit lounge while passing through will need a valid Australia visa type. Travelers on an Australia transit visa are allowed to leave the airport and stay in Australia for up to 72 hours before traveling onto their next destination.

([Source](https://www.australiaonlinevisa.org/types/transit-visa/))

Comment: @Crystal No problem, if I helped please press the tick next to my answer. Thanks